# How to start Windows CMD without output of version and copyright information?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Is there any way to avoid the output of the version and copyright information on starting `cmd`?

So it just starts without the version information as shown below:

```
C:\Windows\System32>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1679]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Why is it important? What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When starting a cmd prompt with /K the version confirmation is not shown

[image]